# which is the better approach between CSS or Angular Animations, to support both browser and NativeScript mobile Animations

Tags: css, angular, nativescript, nativescript-angular, angular-animations

I am unclear whether angular animations are my only option or if I can also make use of css animations with the native elements on mobile? How do css animations from an angular application get converted to native mobile? Is it an inferior technique to the way angular animations get converted?

one query I have is about making use of angular animations that have been defined for the browser version and then making use of them for the native elements

shorturl.at/intuO

I am interested in investing time in some animations and I want them to work on both browser and mobile

(3) on-scene-enter
(4) on-scene-exit
(5) on-mouse-down
(6) on-mouse-up
(7) on-drag
(8) on-drop
(9) on-scroll-up
(10) on-scroll-down
(11) on-focus
(12) on-deselect

Comment: short-url provided is dead. Can you update the link?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried Angular Animations, but it is based on CSS, and NativeScript is compatible with CSS animations on native elements, so it should work on both mobile and web. Mobile platforms don't have a DOM like web, but the NativeScript runtime handles converting CSS styles/animations, to native Android/iOS styles/animations.

What I have used with success in my shared Angular NativeScript Mobile/Web projects is, a CSS animation library called [Animate.css](https://animate.style/).  It makes it much easier to apply animations by just specifying an animation name in a CSS class like, `fadeIn`, `slideIn`, `zoomOut`, etc...

```css
.btn-login {
  animation-name: fadeIn;
  animation-duration: 2s;
}
```

*Footnotes:*

> Angular's animation system is built on CSS functionality, which means you can animate any property that the browser considers animatable. This includes positions, sizes, transforms, colors, borders, and more. The W3C maintains a list of animatable properties on its CSS Transitions page.
> https://angular.io/guide/animations

> NativeScript CSS animations are based on the simple and easy to use standard CSS3 animations API. You can use them to animate almost every native view without even having to know JavaScript. You have the potential to alter the appearance and behavior of an element whenever a state change occurs, such as when it is touched or activated. You can use multiple frames and change the animation direction. Finally, with CSS animations, you can separate the animation code from your application logic.
> https://docs.nativescript.org/interaction.html#css-animations